# RedBeanPHP: find all books where property is null?

Tags: php, activerecord, redbean

I tried this, but I dont get any results:

```
$Books= R::findAll( 'books' , ' WHERE accepted IS NULL ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 100 ' );
```

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

My PHP:

```
            $requests = array();

            $Books = R::findAll( 'books' , ' ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 100 ' );

            foreach ($Books as &$value) {
                $request = new stdClass();
                $request->name= $value->name;     
                $request->accepted = $value->accepted;                  
                $request->id = $value->id;                    
                $requests[] = $request;
            }

            print_r(json_encode((object)$requests));
```

In Javascript I do a console.log(object); and i get this:

```
Object
  0: Object
     name: "Mem û Zîn"
     accepted: null
     id: "1"
  1: Object
      ...
```

With the "WHERE" statement and R::findAll I get nothing.

**EDIT:**
OK thx to @gbelisario this works:

```
$Books = R::getAll( 'select * from books WHERE accepted IS NULL ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 100 ' ); 

            foreach ($Books as &$value) {
                $requests[] = $value;
            }


            print_r(json_encode((object)$requests));
```

Comment: We should not see resolving advice edited into the question -- that's what answers are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
R::getAll( 'select * from books WHERE accepted IS NULL ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 100 ' );
```

Comment: hm it didnt work. :( - maybe I should say that I use sqlite?

Comment: The syntax should be the same... Are you sure the field "property" is null and not just empty? Use a client to connect to the database and test the query

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with redbean and it works with

```
R::find ( 'bean', "battribute is NULL" );
```

too